# How can doors be broken?

Tags: pubg-battlegrounds

What are the destruction mechanics for the doors in-game?

Do the doors splinter after a specific amount of damage is dealt? Or do some weapons more easily destroy doors than others?

Comment: They break when you shoot them. They blow open when you use explosives.

Comment: There is some potential to this question, for instance It would be interesting to know if different caliber weapons are more effective at breaking the doors, or if the location that you shoot the doors effects how much damage is done.

Comment: This is a good point to bring up.  I wonder if the doors have any "soft spots" that allow for it to more easily break?  I've also noticed that there are different door types, do these have different health values or do they operate the same in terms of the destruction mechanic?

Comment: @HazyKingdom Wow! I just started doing some tests on this and it is actually far more interesting than I ever thought it would be! (Will update my Answer in the next few days)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

So I did dome testing on this topic and I must say, I was pretty surprised by the results!
I documented (almost) all of my testing and uploaded the video to YouTube [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jCpsMdB1ZRI&feature=youtu.be&ab_channel=JoshuaKoroluk).

**TL;DR:**
Doors will only break, if you shoot them **fast** enough, the amount of damage 
dealt is not that important. Any weapon, able to shoot fairly fast, will be able to destroy a door easily.
"*Just spam it!*"

**Destruction of doors:**
Doors will **always** have 4 stages of destruction:
(only exception are grenades)

```
 1. Fully intact (no holes)
 2. Half broken (top, bottom or middle)
 3. Broken (two parts missing, very few peaces of wood left)
 4. Destroyed (Door is completely gone)
```

In every stage, apart from the last one, the door is still functional.

**Damaging:**
As you can see in the first clip of my [Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jCpsMdB1ZRI&feature=youtu.be&ab_channel=JoshuaKoroluk), I shoot the door a total of **40** times with an **AR**, but the door still doesn't break. Note that I shoot **one bullet per ~0.85s**.
Then I switch to a faster shooting pace and it only takes 3 bullets to destroy a part of the door. (Door is now in stage 2)
For the other half of the door I will also only need **3 rapidly fired** bullets.

**Firing Rate needed:**
I did some very simple calculations on how many bullets per second must be fired in order to break a part of a door:
(These are the results of the **M416**)

```
Bullet1: 46;25
Bullet2: 47;08 (13f = 0,4333333333333333s)
Bullet3: 47;22 (14f = 0,4666666666666667s)

1f + 13f + 14f = 28f = 0,9333333333333333s
```

So it's safe to say, that by shooting **3 bullets within 1 second** you will break a part of the door. (using an M416!)

**Different Weapons:**
Any weapon, able to shoot "*fast enough*", can destroy a door. Here's a list of weapons:

- 3 Bullets

  - M16A4 (5.56mm)
  - M416 (5.56mm)
  - Scar-H (5.56mm)
  - AKM (7.62mm)
  - SKS (7.62mm)
- 4 Bullets

  - UMP-9 (9mm)
  - P1911 (.ACP)
- 5 Bullets

  - P92 (9mm)

**This list is not complete!** I haven't had the opportunity yet to test all of the weapons.

**PLEASE READ:**
Because testing something like this is very time consuming and based on a lot of luck (finding the right weapons whilst not dying) this is all I can answer so far.
**I will definitely update my answer** in the future.

**EDIT:** By "I will definitely update my answer" I mean, that I **might** update my answer...

Comment: would you happen to have the source code or web source where you received this information?

Comment: @HazyKingdom First line in my answer:
*Speaking from my own experience:*

Comment: Quality work @Hulkerman!  Solid gold.

Comment: What about shotguns?

Comment: @Shelby115 Oh yeah I forgot to mention those, but at the time of testing every shotgun could break 1 or sometimes even 2 pieces off the door in a single shot.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to @Hulkerman's answer,

I think doors should be breakable with HE Grenades, Molotov's and Simply ramming a vehicle through it.

I will test it this weekend, but it seems logical :D

Comment: Fun fact: When I tested this, Molotovs could instantly fully break doors, which meant that you could through molotovs through doors without having them bounce back.